# how to parse and display hstore key/value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, hstore

I'ved got a data type that is postgres hstore that stores a json string.

I want to be able to parse and display the key/values on rails html page.

Somehow, I just do not know how to run a parse on the data field and display each one of key/value listed in the string.

```
<% @payment_accounts.each do |payment_account| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= payment_account.name %></td>
    <td><%= payment_account.company %></td>
    <td><%= payment_account.data %></td>        <-- this is the hstore json string
     <td><%= Json.parse(payment_account.data) %></td>   <-- this is an error, just to show

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

example would be payment_account.data contains {"hello"=>"world", "great"=>"job"}

here is the index.html.erb code.
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9174206

what should i do to accomplish this ? that is parsing hstore string to display a query result in rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data like an array:

```
<%= payment_account.data['hello'] %>
```

That will display `world`