# How to return a specific key value from an hstore?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, hstore

I have a psql database that contains an hstore as a column, as such:
column:
"a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3"

In a standalone ruby script, I am correctly accessing my database, but I would like to output a specific value for "a", so that it only returns "1".
When I attempt to do this from a loop it outputs "a" => "1" instead.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
require 'open-uri'
require'activerecord-postgres-hstore'

conn = PGconn.connect("hostname", 1234, '', '', "x", "y", "z")

array = conn.exec('SELECT * FROM database')

  array.each do |uri|
    puts uri['column']
  end
```

The documentation on this page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html
shows that you can use *hstore -> text* to obtain the value, but I am unsure how to do this in ruby.

I have also seen this question [how to parse and display hstore key/value in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971633/how-to-parse-and-display-hstore-key-value-in-rails?rq=1) , but as I said the output gives me both key and value when I only want the value.

I should also say that while the database was created using rails, I do not want to use it for this script.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, add the code used to retrieve `array` variable (`conn.exec()` and related).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to extract the values for the `'a'` keys in `column` then say exactly that and let the database do the work:

```
conn.exec(%q{SELECT column -> 'a' FROM database}).each do |_, a|
  # The value will be in `a`, `_` will be the made up column name.
end
```

or, if you want to work with other things:

```
conn.exec(%q{SELECT other_column, column -> 'a' as col_at_a FROM database}).each do |row|
  # Look at `row['other_column']` and `row['col_at_a']` ...
end
```

Comment: This worked well enough, but the output was more or less the same. I had to add _.values[0] within the loop as well to get the right values in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Then you probably want something more like the second case, use AS in the SQL to give it a name so that you can pull it out of the hash by name.